# Algorithms online problems

Tags: algorithm-analysis, reference-request

I'm trying in vain to find some online (classical) algorithms problems to deeply exercise "complexity" and maybe see (even try) mathematical demonstrations.

As far as I can see, the sites that I found (CodeChef, Project Euler) seem to be more programming oriented, even if I like the format and their challenge. That is, even when speed is somehow important, you cannot not know the exact complexities values for the algorithm (the lovely greek letters), maybe some demonstration of the efficiency of the solution.

An online course or a book is acceptable if it is more problems oriented. In my opinion, these are the kind of questions that a development top company should ask anyway.

Comment: Since the answer is trivially [tag:algorithm-analysis], I don't quite see what you are getting at. (Be careful with your use of "complexity".) You might want to start at our reference questions on [algorithms](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844) and [asymptotics](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/846/98).

Comment: Have you looked at `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms`?

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, I don't understand nothing from your comment

Comment: Possible (stupid) questions: 1) "How many letter i are on the page en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms"? What is the time complexity of the ideal algorithm? or 2) provide an algorithm to calculate the space unused on the SO sites? What is the best case performance?

Comment: @HEKTO http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms is, indeed, the best bet until now, the problem is that is too theoretical, I want more practical problems

Comment: There are algorithms on this page, which are widely used in the world right now - for example `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Sequence_algorithms`.

Comment: @Liviu Practical problems are almost always all but impossible to analyse. Good luck. If you change your mind, feel free to follow the links I provide in my above comment.

Comment: You should be careful with the name *online algorithm*, this term is used for algorithms in which the data is provided sequentially during the runtime - in contrast to *offline algorithms* where you have the full input at hand, when the computation starts.

Answer (score -1):

Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein's *Introduction to Algorithms* (MIT Press, 3rd edition, 2009) is a good book for understanding and solving time complexity and correctness of
algorithms mathematically.

Comment: Still, the post does not answer the question (which requests problems found on the web), however ill-advised it may be.

Comment: @Raphael I'am wrong if he is asking question for competitive programming.

Comment: @Raphael The question says, "An online course or a book is acceptable if it is more problems oriented."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hm, I read "online (course | book)". I agree that "(online course) | book" is a plausible parse.